# Change Lightswitch HTML Client language

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch, multilingual, lightswitch-2012

Is it possible to change the display language and control format to german?
So that the datetime control shows the day seletion first instead of month selection or the yes/no toogle the german words.

I changed the "Default Language" property in the project property page without any result.

Edit:
According to here it seems to be a problem with the new VS 2012 Update 3:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2ce818aa-08d0-46bd-883d-b42202059f3b/language-bug-in-vs2012-update-3-to-ls-team

Temporary solution from Beth Massi: 
After you remove Update 3 (Add/Remove Programs -- View installed Updates) you can reinstall Update 2 from the ISO here: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=298533

Answer (score 1):

You can localize your lightswitch application using this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/xx130603(v=vs.120).aspx

It doesn't mention datetime control, I had this problem before too, I couldn't change the datetime control but I could change how the date is visualized in labels like this:

```
myapp.ViewTable.StartDate_postRender = function (element, contentItem) {
    contentItem.dataBind("value", function (value) {
        if (value) {
            $(element).text(moment(value).format("DD/MM/YYYY"));
        }
    });
};
```

This is a screen called ViewTable and shows a column called StartDate click on "edit postrender code" and put that code. It formats the date into Day/Month/Year. This code is using the momento.js library for handling of dates. There is an article about how to add, you need to switch to file view and add the momento.js library to the project.

Yes/No can be configure in the table (data sources), remember that "Server" must be selected when editing the entity. Look for the column you want to customize, for instance "Retired" the type is a boolean, on the properties window click on Choice List and fill the choices like this: True Ja, False Nicht. That's it all the screens that show that column will be "in german"

Hope this helps.